# Mongo Update just one item in an sub-document and add one item in the same sub document

Tags: mongodb

This is the `document` in my `collection`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d49"),
        "name" : "myapp",
        "openApp" : true,
        "appDeveloper" : "Arun",
        "environments" : [
                {
                        "environment_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d45"),
                        "environment_name" : "production_env_updated",
                        "environment_type" : "prod",
                        "services" : [
                                {
                                        "service_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d46"),
                                        "service_name" : "some_updated",
                                        "service_type" : "..."
                                },
                                {
                                        "service_id" : ObjectId("5d766d45791adb12cc607d4a"),
                                        "service_name" : "updated 2",
                                        "service_type" : "..."
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "environment_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d48"),
                        "environment_name" : "demo_env",
                        "environment_type" : "stage",
                        "services" : [
                                {
                                        "service_id" : ObjectId("5d766d45791adb12cc607d4b"),
                                        "service_name" : "perfectly new",
                                        "service_type" : "perfect"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

I wanted to run a query that would update only `"service_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d46")` within the `services-array` and then add a new `service-object`

I executed the below query and doesn't know how to move further

```
db.app_attributes.update ({"_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d49")}, 

{ '$set': {"environments.services.service_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d46") :  {
                                        "service_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d46"),
                                        "service_name" : "sdfsdf",
                                        "service_type" : "..."
                                }}} 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the subdocument whose `service_id` is `ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d46")`.

You can do it using the [Filtered Positional Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.app_attributes.update(
    {"_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d49")}, 
    {
        $set: {
            "environments.$[].services.$[element]": {
                "service_id" : ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d46"),
                "service_name" : "Updated Service Name",
                "service_type" : "Updated Service Type"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {"element.service_id": ObjectId("5d766c18791adb12cc607d46")}
        ], 
        multi: true
    }
)
```